# Refactoring java switch statement (blackjack)

Tags: java, android

I have this huge block of code in a switch statement for my Java android blackjack game and I've been trying to refactor it but unsure of the best way to clean this up! Currently it's almost unreadable and has bugs that say player has won a hand when the dealer has actually won. Any tips in the right direction or help would be amazing.

```
public void checkTable() {
    switch (tableState) {
        case NEW_GAME:
            setUpNewGame();
            break;

        case PLAYING: {

            Player currentPlayer = this.players.get(currentPlayerIndex);
            Player.State currentState =  currentPlayer.getState();

            if (currentState != Player.State.STAND ||
                    currentState != Player.State.BUST) {
                if (currentPlayer.askAction() == Player.Action.HIT) {
                    currentPlayer.hit(deck.dealCard());
                    if (currentPlayer.getHandValue() > 21) {
                        currentPlayer.setState(Player.State.BUST);
                    } else if (currentPlayer.getHandValue() == 21) {
                        currentPlayer.setState(Player.State.STAND);
                    }
                }

                if (currentPlayer.askAction() == Player.Action.STAND) {
                    currentPlayer.setState(Player.State.STAND);
                    currentPlayer.setAction(Player.Action.WAIT);
                    currentPlayerIndex++;
                }
                else if (currentState != Player.State.BUST) {
                    currentPlayer.setAction(Player.Action.WAIT);
                    currentPlayerIndex++; 
                }
            }
            if (currentPlayerIndex > players.size() - 1)
                tableState = RESOLVE;
            else
                break;
        }
        case RESOLVE:

            while (this.dealer.getHandValue() < 17)
                this.dealer.hit(deck.dealCard());

            if(this.dealer.getHandValue() > 21)
                this.dealer.setState(Player.State.BUST);

            if (this.dealer.getState() == Player.State.BUST) {

                for (int i = 0; i < this.players.size(); i++) {
                    if (this.players.get(i).getState() != Player.State.BUST) {
                        this.players.get(i).setState(Player.State.WON);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < this.players.size(); i++) {
                    if (this.players.get(i).getState() != Player.State.BUST) {
                        if (this.players.get(i).getHandValue() < dealer.getHandValue())
                            players.get(i).setState(Player.State.LOST);
                        if (players.get(i).getHandValue() < dealer.getHandValue())
                            players.get(i).setState(Player.State.WON);
                        if (players.get(i).getHandValue() == dealer.getHandValue())
                            players.get(i).setState(Player.State.PUSH);
                    }
                }
            }

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd start by putting the contents of each switch case into a separate method. Even if they don't make it into your final answer, that will help clean-up this bit of code and make it easier to read.

Comment: Thanks Brick! Am separating them now, still working on tidying the code but splitting them up is a good idea

Answer (score 1):

**In programming, it is not a good practice to write longer methods which will be very hard to understand, test and support.**

You can split the complex logic for each case into separate methods (with meaningful names) as shown below, which makes it more readable and maintainable:

```
public void checkTable() {
    switch (tableState) {
        case NEW_GAME:
            setUpNewGame();
            break;

        case PLAYING:
            handlePlaying();//Move the PLAYING logic to handlePlaying()
            break;

        case RESOLVE:
            handleResolve();//Move the RESOLVE logic to handleResolve()
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

**Also, ensure that all these different methods have been covered with proper unit testing scenarios by using the frameworks like `JUnit`.**

Comment: Thanks javaguy! I will split these up now, but the complex logic going into the handlePlaying and handleResovle will still need some tidying as I'm only new to java and think I let it sprawl!

Answer (score 0):

first off all format your code using the auto formatter of your IDE.

Then assure that same things have same names allover the code. and by any chance repeated consecutive instructions have same order.

reduce the visibility of variables to the smallest possible block. That means if you use the same variable in different branches of your switch declare it there separately (and the only inside the `if`,`else` or `for` block where it is used).

then select the content of any block that does not contain other blocks but has more that 1 line. in your IDE find the "extract method" refactoring and start it. It should bring up a dialog, that lets you enter a name for the new method where it also tells how many occurrences of that same bunch of statements with be replaced in addition to the currently selected. If this in more than 0 then proceed.

If you finished with all the "leaf blocks" that look at the new methods and think if you could put them into a new class (ore more).

maybe this video helps (although it is about c#) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aWiwDdx_rdo

Answer (score -1):

**You can format**

```
if (boolean)
{
    System.out.println("Something"); //Any oneline statement
}
else if (boolean)
{
    System.out.println("Something"); //Any oneline statement
}
```

**as**

```
if (boolean)
    System.out.println("Something"); //Any oneline statement
else if (boolean)
    System.out.println("Something"); //Any oneline statement
```

As you have some if's still formated in the first way and others in the second way. That could improve the readability quite a bit. Also you should move the logic away from the switch like brick commented.

I would have commented this but I don't have the required rep yet.

Comment: Great that's incredibly helpful, I will do this now. Thanks!